# What to test when using TDD and asserts

Tags: python, matlab, unit-testing, tdd

First, I'm a newbie at both TDD and Python. I don't code for a living, but I do write a ton of code.

I'm in the process of moving a large project from Matlab to Python. 1) because the language has been limiting, and 2) when analyzing edge cases and debugging, I was starting to break as much as I was fixing. So I decided I'll start from scratch, with TDD this time.

I get the TDD cycle (red, green, refractor). The question is, -what- does one test? For an individual unit/function, how many tests do you write? In this case, I already have the whole project in my head, even though there will be a few library, and structural, changes between the languages.

Also, I've heard ad nauseam to use asserts everywhere, so I am. But sometimes it seems I'm writing tests to verify my asserts. And it seems like a waste of time to write a valid input type test for every argument, one function at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've ran into the very common realisation across programmers who try to embrace testing (good for you!) - that unit testing, for most part, sucks. Or at the very least is a wrong tool for what you are trying to do.
And this is why I recommend for you to drop the heresy of unit testing and embrace the elegance and beauty of behaviour testing. There even is a fantastic library for it: [behave](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/).

This not only allows you to re-use your code, but also forces you to describe logic of your application in plain English (which, when done right, is equivalent to proper documentation) which helps to narrow logic holes and other design non-senses that may arise. It also removes the problem of "what to test", as with BDD you should test every way the application can behave.

In your specific case you will definitely also be interested in the scenario outline functionality, where you can write the testing code once, and then just write long list of examples to run by this code.

Comment: Good point on the documentation, as I'm doing a much better job of that this go-around. I did run across BDD when trying to get up to speed on TDD, but I guess I discounted it because the TDD crowd is louder. I'll take a look at the library. In the meantime, do you have any pointers for how to quickly integrate BDD testing? I was just getting on a roll with the project conversion with automated pytest runs, and I'm curious how I can switch "gears" without losing too much momentum (all the while realizing that it's easy to be penny-wise, pound-foolish).

Comment: @sParadox it's much simpler than it looks! Just when writing your new feature, start by writing the .feature file, fill it in, describing all the expected behaviours from it, write the code to run the .feature file (at this point you will have to create most of the interfaces that will be used by this new feature, implementation can wait) and then just keep on implementing the stubs you've created. I really don't distinct TDD and BDD apart, as they follow almost identical workflow. The only difference is that they use different testing tool.